# How to show conversion result in a <Textview> box?

Tags: android

How to show the result of convert miles to Km in the middle of the screen with big letter, something similar to a countdown timer or digital clock. I just want show my result in the  instead of .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you finish your conversion, just do this.

`((TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_YOUR_TEXT_VIEW)).setText(CONVERSION_RESULTS);`

It is cleaner to save the result of the `findViewById` to a global variable in onCreate to something like `mConversionTextView` and then just call `mConversionTextView.setText(...);`